# Logic error in batch processing?

Tags: java, loops, jpa, batch-file

By all means I usually debug my stuff for my own, and I also got an alternativ (bloated but working) solution for that, but I can't seem to figure out the logical error in my following batch-code:

```
private int records = 0;
private Query q;

public void BatchProcessor(String className)
        throws Exception {
    int pageSize = 1000;
    boolean done = false;
    List<Test> resultList = null;

    while (!done) {

        q.setFirstResult(records);
        q.setMaxResults(records+pageSize);
        System.out.println("records: "+records);            

        if (records % pageSize == 0) {
            em.clear();
        }

        resultList = q.getResultList();
        process(resultList);
    }
}

private void process(List<Test> list) {
    Iterator<Test> itAmount = list.iterator();
    while (itAmount.hasNext()) {
        Test dto = itAmount.next();
        records=records+1;
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

records: 0
records: 1000
records: 3000
records: 7000
records: 15000
records: 31000
...

This is driving me crazy. Each loop in the while() it seems to start from "0" again as the number of q.setFirstResult() and then the lists grows larger. The list grows larger each iteration until an "Out of Memory" Exception occurs. I also don't get why it doesn't print out at 20000 records, 40000, 50000 etc.
I completely fail to see the fault in this code :( Please, does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Loop without break condition.  Yeah.... You might want to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do not do `q.setMaxResults(records+pageSize)`; You should only do `q.setMaxResults(pageSize)`;

If as your `records` increases you are increasing `MaxResults`

Java doc

> Query setMaxResults(int maxResult)
>
> Set the maximum number of results to retrieve.

The list is increasing because of your `records+pageSize` value

```
records= 0 MaxResults = 1000;
records= 1000 MaxResults = 2000;
```

It should be always like

```
records= 0 MaxResults = 1000;
records= 1000 MaxResults = 1000;
records= 2000 MaxResults = 1000;
```

Comment: Oh my god, that's it. I completely understand that now. I thought I must change the "range" manually with First/MaxResult. Thanks a lot, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

done is never set to true, so it's looping forever.

Then records is set to 0, then to 1000 , then to 3000, then 7000, ...

So your output is normal too ...

```
private int records = 0;
private Query q;

public void BatchProcessor(String className)
        throws Exception {
    int pageSize = 1000;
    int nbofloops = 0;
    boolean done = false;
    List<Test> resultList = null;

    while (!done) {

        q.setFirstResult(pageSize * nbofloops++;);
        q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        System.out.println("records: "+records);            

        if (records % pageSize == 0) {
            em.clear();
        }

        resultList = q.getResultList();
        process(resultList);
    }
}

private void process(List<Test> list) {
    Iterator<Test> itAmount = list.iterator();
    while (itAmount.hasNext()) {
        Test dto = itAmount.next();
        records=records+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I expected that after the first iteration of the while loop the first 1000 results should be processed, then the results from 1000-2000, then the results from 3000-4000 etc. Each time after processing 1000 records the while loop should set the cursor to the new range. I just haven't set the "stop-condition" yet. But as the loop doesn't behave correctly until now, that's a minor issue.

Comment: @Malvin then don't add records to pageSize. PageSize is 1000. So each loop you need to take results from 1000 to 2000, then 2000 to 3000, etc... Which means that you need to set FirstResult(x*PageSize) where x is the number of times you entered the loop.

Comment: `q.setMaxResults(pageSize * nbofloops); ` is wrong it should be always `q.setMaxResults(pageSize)` which will always retrive in  this case `1000` results starting from `q.setFirstResult(records)`